# Pass Pivot.SelectedIndex to user control in Windows 10 universal app

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, win-universal-app

I have a user control and a pivot on the same page.
I would like the user control to show something different based on the selected tab in the pivot.

At first, I thought that I could pass the pivot.SelectedIndex to the user control as a dependency property like so:

```cs
    // Pivot property
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedTabProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
    (
         "SelectedTab",
         typeof(int),
         typeof(GaugeControl),
         new PropertyMetadata(-1)
    );

    public int SelectedTab
    {
        get {
            return (int)GetValue(SelectedTabProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SelectedTabProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

With xaml in the parent page:

```
            <local:GaugeControl
                Data="{x:Bind data_collector}" 
                SelectedTab="{Binding ElementName=MainPivot, Path=SelectedIndex}"
                Margin="0,0,0,100"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

            <Pivot x:Name="MainPivot"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="0,0,0,0"
                   Style="{StaticResource PivotStyleBottomHeader}">
                ....
```

However, this code generates an error `The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread` in the getter.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you build the *GaugeCotrol* or you are using a third party library? I'm not sure if it's not a problem of the control - I've successfully build [a sample app](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=87995A9E6AADB641!59948&authkey=!AHp1mm5VOe_C8ro&ithint=file%2czip), which bind pivot's selected index to usercontrol's dependency property and everything should work. Can you check it out?

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look. The GuageControl is something I wrote, yes.

Comment: Also are you redirecting some work to other threads?

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I believe that was what caused it. My usercontrol uses Win2D to draw a graph and I was accessing the property in its draw method. I thought that was running in the UI thread, but maybe not?

Comment: I'm not sure without seeing the code, it can be. Try to debug it, comment some lines and see the effects. If possible you can share a minimal repro sample and I can take a look at it.